# Multiple recordsets (conditions) inside a single recordset query

Tags: sql

I have some strings passed to my page as url parameters.

For example I have the below url:

```
www.some-site.com/some-page.asp?px_color=72&px_material=32&px_size=111
```

Trying to retrieve the desired products from my PRODUCT table, I know only one way to do that:

`WHERE px_color = 72` (meaning one condition at a time)

Is there any way to query like that?
`px_color=72, px_material=32, px_size=111`  (all together at the same time)??

(DB:MSSQL 2016 / Project: ClassicASP/VBScript)

---

If I'm not wrong, I think what I want is something like a filter recordset, but i am completely unfamiliar with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use IN clause. this will fetch the px_color if there is any

```
where px_color IN (72, 32, 111)
```

If you use IN it is not manadatory that these px_color numbers should be present in table. It will fetch those numbers that are present and ignores the remaining.

and in case if you are going to use character or date value inside the 
IN clause put them inside single codes separated with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AND for add  more conditio to where clause

```
    select your_col 
    from your_table  

    WHERE px_color = 72 
    AND px_material = 32 
    AND px_size = 111
```